# How many different graphs are there with a given degree-sequence?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Let G be a simple undirected graph. If it has at most $4$ edges, there is only one
 graph for any degree-sequence, but for $n = 5$, the situation changes. There are
 $34$ different (non-isomorphic) graphs, but only $31$ degree-sequences. For $n\ge 6$
 the discrepance becomes already quite large.

According to wikipedia, no efficient algorithm is known to determine whether two
 given graphs are isomorphic. But I wonder if the enumeration and the calculation
 of the number of different graphs is easier :

- How many different graphs do exist for a given degree-sequence ?
- What is the best method to enumerate the different graphs ?