# How many (non-isomorphic) graphs are there with a given degree sequence?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a general (and efficient) method to determine how many graphs there are with a given degree sequence $S$? How many isomorphism classes are there among those?

Is the question different for digraphs, i.e. how many directed graphs are there with a degree sequence $S$ (list of pairs of integers)?

**Tentative answer:** As an approximation, one could count the number of (non-isomorphic) graphs of $n$ nodes divided by the number of distinct degree sequences for graphs of $n$ nodes.

Another approach is to generate many random graphs with degree sequence $S$ (e.g. with Havel-Hakimi), and determine the fraction of isomorphic classes. However this is a very rough estimation and would be inefficient for large $n$. Moreover, I am not sure that Havel-Hakimi or similar techniques cover all possible graphs, and whether they do so with uniform probability.

Comment: This [was asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935621/how-many-different-graphs-are-there-with-a-given-degree-sequence) but received no answer then.

Comment: Various scattered Google results here and on MathOverflow contained just partial answers for special cases, such as [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77730/how-many-p-regular-graphs-with-n-vertices-are-there) about merely the  _asymptotic_ growth rate for how many $p$-regular graphs there are. This looks like the general problem is still wide open.